# "AND" relation in custom taxonomies

Tags: taxonomy

I've 5 custom taxonomies in my WP theme, and I build rewrite rules correctly, but, when I put all taxonomies in the URL i noticed that WP core Works with "OR" filter instead "AND". **I need "AND" relation**

The url structure is like this:

```
www.domain.com/tax1/value/tax2/value/tax3/value/tax4/value/tax5/value
```

Can I change this relation?

I'm working with `index.php` template

Comment: Have you written any custom function for taxonomy filter ? And please share your `.htaccess` or your rewrite_rule file.

Answer (score 0):

@the_dramatist My `functions.php` file contains:

```
function core_rewrite_rules() {

    global $wp_rewrite;

    $new_rules = array(

'tax1/(.+?)/tax2/(.+?)/tax3/(.+?)/tax4/(.+?)/tax5/(.+?)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=my-custom-post-type&tax1=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '&tax2=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) . '&tax3=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(3) . '&tax4=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4) . '&tax5=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4),

    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'core_rewrite_rules' );
```

My autogenerated htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```